# First Difference Estimator and Levels mixed up

Tags: fixed-effects-model, standardization

I read a paper which used the first difference estimator in an empirical analysis and while reading, some questions arose and that is why I would like to ask you for help.

At first the authors standardized all variables (so z-scores)
The next step was the explanation of the first difference operator they used $(Y_t-Y_{t-1})$:
$$Δ y = b_0 Δx + b_1 Δt + b_2 Δr \tag{1}$$

On the next step they explained that the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test rejects the null-hypothesis for $y$ in levels. That is why they will use $y$ in levels and their set up changed into:
$$y = b_0 Δx + b_1 t + b_2 Δr  \quad\quad\text{(now $y$ and $t$ are in levels)} \tag{2}$$

**Question:** If my variables are stationary (ADF-Test rejects null-hypothesis), and I use z-score variables, can I combine levels and first differences like in equation (2)?

If so, how would I interpret the coefficients then?

Comment: For your future reference when you are writing papers for publication: the pronoun "I" is always capitalized.